# Quick release wheels on kids bikes?

Tags: wheels, frugal, children, quick-release

Currently trying to find larger bikes for our kids aged 5 & 7. Oldest's next bike is going to be a struggle to fit in the back of the car (for various reasons they cycle to school in the morning and car it back in the evening, so this is important).

Seemingly there are no kids' bikes with quick release wheels. Problem is most ebay sellers are rubbish at describing their bikes in detail so it's hard to tell what's on offer.

Is this because quick-release wheels in kids bikes are non-existant? If they exist, what brands should we be looking out for?

*(Ebay is where we go for children's bikes. There may be hard-core purists here who'll tell us to go to the nearest independent bike shop for the perfect bike and blow the cost, but there's so much value in second-hand kids bikes we can't justify buying new. Plus they so quickly grow on to the next one)*

Comment: [This question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/can-i-just-change-straightforward-wheel-axles-to-qr-skewers) may be helpful to you if you opt to convert non-QR wheels to QR.

Comment: Yeah, if you can find a hollow axle with the right diameter and thread pitch you can upgrade the wheels to use skewers.  Find the right parts and a bike shop could easily swap them for you, if you can't do it.  The question is whether you can find the right parts -- may be easy, may be hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think I've seen quick release on kids bikes, you could always use a wing-nut to make them quicker to remove.

Have you looked at the racks that just clip onto the back of the car (trunk/boot)  - a lot quicker and easier than getting bikes into the back of the car.

Comment: Wing-nut is an excellent low cost idea. I'm assuming any quick-release options are going to be amongst the expensive high-end bikes. And i've just added the [frugal] tag.

Comment: racks ... our situation is a bit complicated, at least two different cars picking up, possibly three, don't want to be shuffling racks around