# Can I use a hollow rear axle without a quick release shaft?

Tags: rear-wheel, axle

Does quick release shaft works also as an extra protection/strength ? And if I don't have it, can the hollow axle break more easily ?

*I bought the wrong one on the web, in the picture I didn't saw that it was hollow.*

[image]

Comment: The QR stops the axle falling out of the frame. Using  an axle designed for a QR skewer with nothing in there would be a very bad idea. I've seen threads on the end of hollow axles, but there's never enough accessible to screw a nut onto (by design, QRs wouldn't work if there was). Maybe take a picture of what you propose and add it to your question.

Comment: "QR stops the axle falling out of the frame" - I know that - that's for those people who have QR shaft. I was asking how safe it is to use hollow axle without a QR but just regular nuts who hold the axle in place.

I bought the one that had axle nuts on both sides. (2nd axle from the top in the picture)

Comment: The problem is that your average QR axle is not long enough to install nuts on the outside, nor is it necessarily threaded over enough length to allow nuts to be installed, even if you got an extra long one.

Comment: If your axel really was supplied with nuts and is long enough for the axel to come all the way through the nuts, then it will be fine. I would guess they're just cutting all their axels from the same stock.

Comment: It just occurred to me that what might be the case is that you may have a hollow axle that *is not* designed for a QR skewer but is in fact intended to be used with nuts. Is that possible? The hollow aspect allows for weight savings, not for a QR skewer.

Comment: There are hollow 3/8" nutted axles within BMX. I think the hole is usually smaller than on a QR hub. I don't have any proof of this, but it intuitively feels to me like those hubs use a less hardened, more ductile axle than a QR hub does.

Comment: That's why I asked for a picture. It sounds like the underlying question is "have I just bought a hollow nutted axle?"

Answer (score 4):

The skewer is not a load-bearing component of the hub axle. It serves *only* to tightly clamp the dropouts around the sides of the hub. If you have an alternate method of doing so (e.g., threaded nuts), you don't need the QR skewers.

I'm concerned that an axle designed for QR skewers probably isn't also capable of having a nut tightly threaded on both ends, so in practice this probably isn't possible. If threads extend out past the dropouts for nuts to be installed, I don't see how the ends of a QR skewer could press against the dropouts, without a specially-designed skewer. But *if* you can clamp your hub to the dropouts, whether or not the axle is hollow shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

A properly installed QR compresses the axle and keeps it under compression while riding. QR Axles are relatively brittle and prone to breakage if the QR is not done up tightly, without a QR, this would be a likely outcome.

Additionally the compression caused by the QR will tighten bearings. If you install a QR Axle using nuts, you would need to ensure the bearings were set-up correctly

[It may be worth getting a set of QR's and running them](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/can-i-just-change-straightforward-wheel-axles-to-qr-skewers)